# Can you integrate your pre-trained word embeddings in a custom spaCy model?

Tags: spacy, word-embedding, named-entity-recognition

Currently I am trying to develop a spaCy model for NER in the romanian legal domain. I was suggested to use specific WE that are presented at the following link (the links to download the WE are on the last pages - slides 25, 26, 27):

https://www1.ids-mannheim.de/fileadmin/kl/CoRoLa_based_Word_Embeddings.pdf

I already trained and tested a model without "touching" the pre-implemented WE but I do not know how to use external WE in computing a new spaCy model. Any relevant advice is appreciated. Although, an example of code will be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, convert your vectors from word2vec text format with `spacy init vectors` and then specify that model as `[initialize.vectors]` in your config along with `include_static_vectors = true` for the relevant tok2vec models.

A config excerpt:

```
[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["ORTH", "SHAPE"]
rows = [5000, 2500]
include_static_vectors = true

[initialize]
vectors = "my_vector_model"
```

You can also use `spacy init config -o accuracy config.cfg` to generate a sample config including vectors that you can edit and adjust as you need.

See:

- https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-vectors
- https://spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers#static-vectors